# WKExtendedRuntimeSession stopping after about 30 seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watch, watchos

This is TRULY maddening me. I’ve tried all sorts of combinations here to even get to this point. It works sometimes and not others. And when it does work it stops by itself while in the background. Please help. I’m a total noob to coding in general and been trying many different methods so I apologize about the jankiness.

```
    if inspectionTime == true {
        if stopWatchManager.mode == .stopped {
            ZStack{
            HStack {
                if stopWatchManager.minutesElapsed > 0 {
                    if stopWatchManager.secondsElapsed < 10 {
                    Text("\(stopWatchManager.minutesElapsed) :0")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
                            stopWatchManager.resetToZero()
                        })
                        .foregroundColor(isPressingDown ? .green : .white)
                        
                        .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                            .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
                            .updating($isPressingDown) { value, state, transaction in
                                
                                switch value {
                                    case .second(true, nil): //This means the first Gesture completed
                                        state = true
                                        
                                    default: break
                                }
                            })
                }
                 else   {
                    Text("\(stopWatchManager.minutesElapsed) :")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
                            stopWatchManager.resetToZero()
                        })
                        .foregroundColor(isPressingDown ? .green : .white)
                        
                        .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                            .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
                            .updating($isPressingDown) { value, state, transaction in
                                
                                switch value {
                                    case .second(true, nil): //This means the first Gesture completed
                                        state = true
                                        
                                    default: break
                                }
                            })
                }
                }
                Text("\(stopWatchManager.secondsElapsed, specifier: "%.02f")")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
                stopWatchManager.resetToZero()
                
                
            })
            
            .foregroundColor(isPressingDown ? .green : .white)
            
            .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
                .updating($isPressingDown) { value, state, transaction in
                    
                    switch value {
                        case .second(true, nil): //This means the first Gesture completed
                            state = true
                            
                        default: break
                    }
                })
            .onChange(of: isPressingDown, perform: { value in
                if isPressingDown == false {
                    if session.state == WKExtendedRuntimeSessionState.notStarted{
                        session.start()}
                    if showCountdown == false {

                        showCountdown = true
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 13.5){
                            if showCountdown == true {
                                stopWatchManager.start()
                                showCountdown = false}
                        }
                    }
                    else if showCountdown == true{
                    stopWatchManager.start()
                    showCountdown = false
                    
                    }
                    turnGreen = false
                    
                }
                else if isPressingDown == true{
                //    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5){
                        WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.click)

                //    }
                    

                }
                if showCountdown == true && isPressingDown == true {
                   turnGreen = true
                }
            })

        }
                if showCountdown == true {
                    CountdownView()}
                Rectangle()
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
                        stopWatchManager.resetToZero()
                        showCountdown = false
                    })
                    .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                        .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
                        .updating($isPressingDown) { value, state, transaction in
                            
                            switch value {
                                case .second(true, nil): //This means the first Gesture completed
                                    state = true
                                    
                                default: break
                            }
                        })
                    .opacity(0.1)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                        .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
                                .updating($testing) { value, state, transaction in
                            
                            switch value {
                                case .second(true, nil): //This means the first Gesture completed
                                    state = true
                                    
                                default: break
                            }
                        })
        }
        }
       else if stopWatchManager.mode == .running {
        ZStack{
        HStack{
        if stopWatchManager.minutesElapsed > 0 {
            if stopWatchManager.secondsElapsed < 10 {
            Text("\(stopWatchManager.minutesElapsed) :0")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
                    stopWatchManager.resetToZero()
                })
                .foregroundColor(isPressingDown ? .green : .white)
                
                .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                    .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
                    .updating($isPressingDown) { value, state, transaction in
                        
                        switch value {
                            case .second(true, nil): //This means the first Gesture completed
                                state = true
                                
                            default: break
                        }
                    })
        }
         else   {
            Text("\(stopWatchManager.minutesElapsed) :")
                .font(.largeTitle)
              //  .frame(width: 500.0, height: 500.0)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture(count: 2, perform: {
                    stopWatchManager.resetToZero()
                })
                .foregroundColor(isPressingDown ? .green : .white)
                
                .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                    .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
                    .updating($isPressingDown) { value, state, transaction in
                        
                        switch value {
                            case .second(true, nil): //This means the first Gesture completed
                                state = true
                                
                            default: break
                        }
                    })
        }
        }
            Text(String(format: "%.02f", stopWatchManager.secondsElapsed))


                .font(.largeTitle)
                //.frame(width: 500.0, height: 500.0)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    if stopWatchManager.mode == .running {
                        stopWatchManager.stop()
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: stopWatchManager.secondsElapsed, perform: {value in
                        if stopWatchManager.secondsElapsed >= 60{
                            stopWatchManager.secondsElapsed = 0
                            stopWatchManager.minutesElapsed = stopWatchManager.minutesElapsed + 1

                        }})
            
    }
        Rectangle()
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture{
            if stopWatchManager.mode == .running {
                stopWatchManager.stop()
            }
            }
            .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                .sequenced(before: LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity))
                .updating($isPressingDown) { value, state, transaction in
                    
                    switch value {
                        case .second(true, nil): //This means the first Gesture completed
                            state = true
                            
                        default: break
                    }
                })
            .opacity(0.01)
            .foregroundColor(.black)}}}

    class StopWatchManager: ObservableObject {
    var session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
    let scoreList = ScoreList()
    @AppStorage("countdown") var countdown = "15"

    @AppStorage("bigDNF") var bigDNF: Bool = false

    @Published var secondsElapsed = 0.00
    @Published var minutesElapsed = 0

    @Published var mode: stopWatchMode = .stopped
    @State private var timeRemaining = 100
    let countdownTimer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @ObservedObject var scoreStore = ScoreStore()
    @AppStorage("newScore") var newScore = ""
    @AppStorage("save") var save = false
    @AppStorage("plus2") var plus2 = false

    var timer = Timer()
    
    

    func start() {
        session = WKExtendedRuntimeSession()
        if session.state == WKExtendedRuntimeSessionState.notStarted{
            session.start()}

        mode = .running
        WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.start)
        secondsElapsed = 0
        minutesElapsed = 0

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.01, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.secondsElapsed += 0.01
        }
        
    }
    func stop() {
        let formattedSeconds = String(format: "%.02f", secondsElapsed)
        
        timer.invalidate()
        
        mode = .stopped
        WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.start)
        
        if plus2 == true {
        secondsElapsed = secondsElapsed + 2
        }
        //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0)

        if minutesElapsed > 0{
            
            newScore = "\(minutesElapsed) :\(formattedSeconds)"
            save = true
        }
        else {
            newScore = "\(formattedSeconds)"

        }
        save = true
        
       // session.invalidate()


    }
    
    func resetToZero() {
            
            secondsElapsed = 0
        minutesElapsed = 0
        WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.click)
        bigDNF = false

    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: What sort of extended runtime session have you configured in your info.plist? This probably isn't the best way to create a stop watch to be honest.  All you need to do is record the `Date` when the stopwatch starts and then you can easily determine elapsed time.  You only need a timer to periodically update the elapsed time when your app is actually on screen. If you persist the start date (say in `UserDefaults`) then you don't need your app to keep running. This is much more battery efficient

Comment: I will have to look into that method, thank you! I’m still super new to coding entirely and had found this method when researching.

With this method, however, I’ve not touched the plots file itself. I did setup the background mode to a physical therapy session type. And even tried enabling audio on it. 

I’m seeing some error in the console as well: “ Error Domain=com.apple.CarouselServices.SessionErrorDomain Code=19 "no client found for pid"” and “ WKExtendedRuntimeObject was dealloced while running. Invalidating the session”

Answer (score 0):

WatchOS deliberately limits the opportunities to execute in the background as it can drain the battery.  There is no need for a background task to implement a stopwatch.

You need a timer running when your app is on screen in order to periodically update the display.  To track elapsed time, you can simply record the `Date` at which the stopwatch was started.  Since time always moves forward you don't need a background task when the app isn't on screen.  When the user returns to your app, you can simply calculate and display the elapsed time based on that start date.

I have included a minimal stopwatch view below.  Note that `UserDefaults` can't store `Date` objects, so I have stored the start date as a `Double` - The time since the reference date.

There is also no need for gesture recognisers - You can simply use a `Button`

```
struct StopwatchView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("running") var running = false
    @AppStorage("started") var started = Date.distantPast.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @AppStorage("minutes") var elapsedMinutes = 0
    @AppStorage("seconds") var elapsedSeconds = 0
    @State var elapsed = "00:00"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(elapsed).onReceive(timer) { input in
                self.elapsed = elapsedTime()
            }.font(.system(.headline, design: .monospaced))
            Spacer()
            Button( action: {
                self.running.toggle()
                if self.running {
                    self.started = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
                }
            }) {
                Text(self.running ? "Stop":"Start")
            }.buttonStyle(BorderedButtonStyle(tint: self.running ? Color.red : Color.green))
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
    
    func elapsedTime() -> String {
        if self.running {
            
            let startDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: self.started)
            let elapsedTime = max( Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate),0)
            elapsedMinutes = Int(elapsedTime / 60)
            elapsedSeconds = Int(elapsedTime - Double(elapsedMinutes * 60))
        }
        
        return String(format:"%02d:%02d",elapsedMinutes,elapsedSeconds)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I’m looking into this now. 

Pardon my ignorance, as again totally new, but how would I set that up with a timer that is like 00:00.00? Thank you so so much!!

Comment: Much as I have done for the minutes and seconds; divide by 3600 to get the integer number of hours, then subtract the integer number of hours multiplied by 3600 to get the renaming minutes (in seconds) then use the code that is there

Comment: Thanks a million for your help! I’m making wonderful progress with your suggestions. One road block I’m at (as I do have the decimals now appearing) they’re only updating at 1 second at a time and making it in sync with the seconds. Whereas it should be running much faster, as expected with a stopwatch.

Comment: Then you need to reduce the timer delay and display the fractional seconds (make `elapsedSeconds` a `Double` and remove the `Int()` when you calculate it.